# WiFi connectivity issues with RTL8852AE, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on Lenovo Yoga 6

Tags: 22.04, realtek-wireless

I can connect to a WiFi hotspot on my phone (Pixel 6 Pro) perfectly fine, the trouble is connecting directly to a router, either the one at work or the one I own at home. The two routers mentioned are a TP-Link AX6000 and ASUS RT-AX92U respectively; I have admin access to both if that is necessary for troubleshooting.

The problem is that, while I can eventually connect to the routers in question, the connection is insanely slow compared to a wired connection or the mobile hotspot.
(76.95% slower download, 99.64% slower upload)

The network interface in my system is RTL8852AE; I have used [rtw89](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89) for the driver and didn't see anything out of the ordinary while installing except for the following:

`$ make`

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic/build M=/home/richie/test/rtw89 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-52-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
...
```

However it seems to continue installing after this.

While attempting to connect to a router, `sudo dmesg -W | grep wlp2s0` returns:

```
[14095.433767] wlp2s0: authenticate with f0:2f:74:2d:70:50
[14095.548887] wlp2s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 (try 1/3)
[14095.579112] wlp2s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 (try 2/3)
[14095.610651] wlp2s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 (try 3/3)
[14095.641617] wlp2s0: authentication with f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 timed out
...
```

Repeated serveral times before either connecting, or giving up. This output is the same wether the network in question has a password, or is open.

If I can get a connection to the router, `sudo dmesg -W | grep wlp2s0` produces:

```
[14787.055170] wlp2s0: authenticate with f0:2f:74:2d:70:50
[14787.169917] wlp2s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 (try 1/3)
[14787.198960] wlp2s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 (try 2/3)
[14787.231289] wlp2s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 (try 3/3)
[14787.264220] wlp2s0: authentication with f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 timed out
[14800.251693] wlp2s0: authenticate with f0:2f:74:2d:70:50
[14800.367102] wlp2s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 (try 1/3)
[14800.380225] wlp2s0: authenticated
[14800.380876] wlp2s0: associate with f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 (try 1/3)
[14800.461250] wlp2s0: associate with f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 (try 2/3)
[14800.535122] wlp2s0: associate with f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 (try 3/3)
[14800.578343] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from f0:2f:74:2d:70:50 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=24)
[14800.689233] wlp2s0: associated
[14800.689533] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by f0:2f:74:2d:70:50
[14800.805332] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
```

After a succsessful connection to my mobile hotspot, `sudo dmesg -W | grep wlp2s0` returns:

```
[14466.133785] wlp2s0: authenticate with 12:69:66:80:63:a6
[14466.266220] wlp2s0: send auth to 12:69:66:80:63:a6 (try 1/3)
[14466.267440] wlp2s0: authenticated
[14466.268846] wlp2s0: associate with 12:69:66:80:63:a6 (try 1/3)
[14466.272544] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 12:69:66:80:63:a6 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[14466.385324] wlp2s0: associated
[14466.385729] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 0 (-128 - 0) dBm as advertised by 12:69:66:80:63:a6
[14466.476952] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
```

This is my first SE question, and I was unsure what information was necessary so I apologize if there is too much info or too little and I can edit in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable some of the driver options, one at a time, reboot and try connecting again.
You can create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/50-rtw89.conf`, and add one line at a time:

```
options rtw89pci disable_aspm_l1=y
options rtw89pci disable_aspm_l1ss=y
options rtw89pci disable_clkreq=y
```

You might also want to choose the 2.4Ghz wireless access point, instead of the faster 5Ghz one, if your router presents 2 of them.